# a href is https:// but it is openning the page as http://

Tags: html, http, https, href

I have a link that links to an https:// page, but when chrome loads the link, it loads it as http:// the https:// works when I type in the direct url, and from other pages, but not from my main page.

Link removed for privacy

Comment: Opened as https for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edited my nameserver to serve all requests as https:// Solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab.

[image: Network tab]

Your server is responding to the request for the document hosted on HTTPS by telling the browser that it can be found on HTTP.

Comment: How would I fix this then? It's only on this page, and works fine on the other pages.

Comment: @sub6resources — Examine your server configuration to find out *why* it is issuing that redirect, then change it.